# Merge setting variable to 0 and iterating a table using the variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

How to merge the queries?

```
SET @i = 0;
```

and

```
SELECT (@i:=@i+1) as i, booking.* from booking;
```

Is there any way without "CREATE PROCEDURE" and "CREATE INDEX"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross join on a query that sets the variable:

```
SELECT (@i:=@i+1) as i, booking.* 
FROM
  booking
  CROSS JOIN (select @i := 0) x;
```

Comment: I think it's the most effective way there is.

Comment: So there is no way to set default value of @i  to 0, not to NULL, in order to simply get rid of "SET" statement ?

Comment: I think that is exactly what my query does. Why do you think it is not effective?

Comment: Because it seems a bit complicated for the action it performs. Of course i'm not a specialist in SQL, but i've heard that "CROSS JOIN" is an expensive operation, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, in general it is, because you get a Cartesian product of the two tables/queries that are cross joines. In this case though, it selects only one value, which is not even selected from a table, but just a variable in memory. It's basically a trick to be able to do this in one query and to reset the variable only once, and it shouldn't give much overhead when used like this.